# CSS text-shadow 1px retina

Tags: fonts, retina-display, css

CSS doubles 1px text-shadow to 2px on retina screens. I need just 1px. Any solutions? 0.5px not working.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried for text-shadow, and don't have a retina screen handy, but for box-shadow [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow) says that for the spread radius:

> "Positive values will cause the shadow to expand and grow bigger,
>   negative values will cause the shadow to shrink. If not specified, it
>   will be 0 (the shadow will be the same size as the element)"

That means you can use:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
```

for instance.

As I say, I haven't tried for text-shadow, but I suspect it should work fine.

Comment: That sucks – it looks like it should…

Answer (score -1):

There is a [lengthy article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/) on smashing magazine that discusses the issue of CSS on retina displays.

Comment: tl;dr. Is there any part of that article that directly addresses the issue at hand? Otherwise this is not a very helpful answer.

Comment: The article is quite helpful IMO. I'd recommend the css media query technique `@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)` mentioned in the article for targeting high density displays with low css pixel density.